# Azure-Database connection string

Tags: azure

I am trying to the the database running on Azure with Angular and Asp.Net core.

Locally I got the Azure-Connection-String entered, and it works, but as soon I push it to azure.

I see in the Console:

message: "Http failure response for https://...: 500 Internal Server Error" ​status: 500 ​statusText: "Internal Server Error"

Here I don't know what to do, I even checked "Use this connection string at runtime"(publish, Azure, Config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried toggling on the, 'Allow Access to Azure Services' where you configured the Azure SQL Database firewall to whitelist your IP while developing on local?

[image: Portal]

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2016/04/11/what-should-i-know-when-setting-up-my-azure-sql-database-paas/

The error is really vague. I'd push up a customErrors off change and try to get more information from the response in your Console -> Network Area.

https://www.edureka.co/community/42369/how-to-debug-azure-500-internal-server-error